# Can't get bootloader to work using easyBCD

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-8, easybcd

When rebooting the computer, only Windows 8 will be visible in bootloader.

- Computer: HP Envy 17
- OS 1: Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit
- OS 2: Windows 8 64 bit

**Disk partitions on system:**

(data from windows disk management)

[image: screenshot]

Disk 1 is a SSD

```
**Disk 0 Dynamic 596,17 GB**
Volum: SYSTEM, type: dynamic, filesystem: NTFS, status: ok (system), capacity: 199 MB
Volum: (D:), type: dynamic, filesystem: NTFS, status: ok, capacity: 595,97 GB

**Disk 1 Default 223,57 GB**
Volum: SYSTEM (M:), type: default, filesystem: NTFS, status: ok (active, primary partition), capacity: 199 MB
Volum: (C:), type: default, filesystem: NTFS, status: ok (startup, primary partition), capacity: 166,42 GB
Volum: , type: default, filesystem: , status: ok (primary partition), capacity: 51,00 GB
Volum: , type: default, filesystem: , status: ok (primary partition), capacity: 5,95 GB
```

**Ubuntu** is installed on the 51,00 GB partition.

**Windows** is istalled on the 166,42 GB partition (C:).

**Pasted from easyBCD:**

```
There are a total of 2 entries listed in the bootloader.
Default: Windows 8
Timeout: 5 seconds

EasyBCD Boot Device: D:\

Entry #1
Name: Windows 8
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #2
Name: NeoSmart Linux
BCD ID: {f3b2e917-5e47-11e2-be84-cc52af78aa22}
Device: Unknown
Bootloader Path: \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
```

Comment: Could the "Device: Unknown" have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I'd like to suggest you UNetbootin. Try to reinstal with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this guide for [dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 8](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html).

Chainloading Ubuntu from Windows 7/8 can be done using either:

1. Ubuntu's boot sector file "boot.img" or
2. installing Ubuntu's boot loader to partition

and chaining it with a Windows boot sector loader.